# Python - Using FancyURLopener, ssl exception - violation of protocol

Tags: python, url, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

Please refer to the following code:

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import FancyURLopener

class ParanoidURLopener(FancyURLopener):
     def http_error_default(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers):
         raise Exception('URL fetch failure on {}: {} -- {}'.format(url, errcode, errmsg))

ParanoidURLopener().retrieve("https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.pkl.gz", "a.pkl.gz")
```

I get the

```
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)
```

I searched around, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512538/fancyurlopener-failing-since-moving-to-python-3-1-2) question on SO, but it is very old bug and seems fixed (code in that question works for me).

`PS_1`: code is taken from [Keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/9d0cf9fbfa420cc72e1f06879a350915f8ffc791/keras/datasets/data_utils.py)
`PS_2`: this is more to the point version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872174/python-3-5-ssl-ssleoferror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol-ssl-c645) question

**EDIT_1**

These errors happen with this file only.

If I open a `pdf` file, it works perfectly.

```
>>> ParanoidURLopener().retrieve("http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/Hands-onPythonTutorial.pdf", "a.pdf")
('a.pdf', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x7f623da36128>)
```

and with this as well it works

```
>>> ParanoidURLopener().retrieve("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "a.gz")
('a.gz', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x7f623da36860>)
```